# Matlab, Convert cell to matrix

Tags: matlab

Hope some of you can help me. I have converted a pdf with a lot of txt and tables to .txt file. I did this because three values of the pdf has to be writen into exel. This has to be done more than a thusind times a mounth, therefore i thought there has to be a better eay than doing it manually. The only things that has to be extracted is the Date, Repport number and a single volume. I found out that the date and repport number always is at the same line, so thats pretty easy to extract, even though its readen into a 145x1 cell. But this brings me to my first question.

Each of the cells looks like this:
Date                   23/4-2015
Repportnumber              8
How do i remove the whitespace?

I also have to extract the volume. this was more difficult, cause the linemunber of the volume differentiates from one pdf to another, therefore i created a searchfunction, which works and founds the volume, which is created to a cellarry looking like this:

[233.4       452.2       94.6]

I only needs the middlenumber, so how do i create this into a matrix?
Keep in mind it is a 1x1 cell, with whitespace!

Hope some of you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you can remove the spaces by searching the line of characters and identifying the spaces with `strcmp`, then setting those elements of the character string to be empty (`[]`). Here is an example of the code for that:

```
% number of character
N = length(my_string);

% character to remove (initialize all 0)
icut = zeros(1,N);

% check each character
for i = 1:N;
    % if character is a space, tag for removal
    if strcmp(my_string(i),' ');
        icut(i) = 1;
    end
end

% remove space characters
my_string(icut == 1) = [];
```

For your second question, you can convert the contents of the cell to a numeric array then simply take the 2nd element.

```
% convert the cell contents to an array of numbers
cell_array = str2num(my_cell{1});

% get the middle value
middle_value = cell_array(2);
```

This assumes the cell contains the array of values as a string, as in `my_cell = {'[233.4 452.2 94.6]'};`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the whitespace from a string using [`strrep`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html). This works on `cell`s containing strings or on `char` arrays and returns the same object type that it was applied to. If you pass in a `cell` to `strrep` it will return a `cell`, if you pass in a `char` array it will return a `char` array.

```
>> C = {'Date 23/4-2015 Repportnumber 8'};
>> strrep(C, ' ', '') % Cell containing string (char array)
ans = 

    'Date23/4-2015Repportnumber8'
>> strrep(C{1}, ' ', '') % String (char array)
ans =

Date23/4-2015Repportnumber8
```

To convert the version cell array to a matrix you can use [`str2num`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html). Then you can use linear indexing to extract the correct version.

```
>> C = {'[233.4 452.2 94.6]'};
>> C = str2num(C{1});
>> C(2)
ans =

  452.2000
```